# Import properties, how get the id? Shopware6

Tags: import, shopware, shopware6

I have a problem with the Shopware 6 import for properties. I would like all properties to be imported with the respective name of the property and the name of the value, instead of id and group_id. Is there a way to be able to do this? Currently this would always just duplicate. If not, is there a way to get the ids efficiently before starting an import?

I tried to just leave the ids empty but this not working. Just duplicating the properties.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the import you can use the [Advanced Settings](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-en/settings/importexport#second-unique-identifier) to set an alternative identifier for each entity imported, as defined by the mapping of CSV column to field.

First you'll need to duplicate the default profile for properties and may then edit the duplicated profile. Then under Advanced Settings you can find the entities for property groups and options. For both of them you may change the identifier from `id` to `translations.DEFAULT.name`. At that point you may also delete the `id` and `group.id` fields from the mapping. From then on you can import properties and their respective group simply by using the name as identifier. So if a property with the exact same name already exists, it will be updated instead of created. Keep in mind that this change will obviously not allow properties with the same name to exist twice.

Comment: I just did it and encountered this problem:
If i have 2 group_name which are different and the name of the property itself which is equal:

Color = green
InsideColor = green

In the Import the color would be imported, the green value not. Instead the InsideColor would be imported with the value green.

Comment: Yes, this is the downside of not using actual ids but descriptive names as identifiers, which is why it is not the default behavior. If you don't want to provide IDs you have to use truly unique names as identifiers, e.g. name one property `green` and the other `green (inside)`.

Comment: Isn't here any other approaches which can be easier done with the normal import? Isn't there a way to get the IDs from Shopware?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean this function:
https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-en/settings/importexport#second-unique-identifier
You can configure in the profile a second unique identifier, in your case the name of the property group and the property value. I hope this can help you.